# How to find the most common column combinations in Excel

Tags: excel

**Narrative**

I have an Excel sheet like this

| Customer ID | Product1 | Product2 | Product3 | Product4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | + | + | - | - |
| 2 | + | + | + | + |
| 3 | - | + | - | + |

The '+' and '-' icons show whether the Customer bought the related Product or not.

**Question**

How can I get most frequent combinations (pairs or trio) of products and their occurences.
For instance in this case it will be:

Product1 & Product2 - 2 times

Product2 & Product4 - 2 times

I have 30 products.

Comment: Do you have four products, or is it just an example? Do you have an upper limit on the number of products?

Comment: @Sergey It is just an example. I have 30 products.

Comment: You would be better off offloading the task to some other technology (sql or some high-level programming language, such as C/C++/Java/C#/Python/etc.) Compute a bitmask for each row using `+` as `1` and `-` as `0` (the first row would be binary 1100, the second row would be 1111, and the third row would be 0101, i.e. decimal 12, 15, and 5). Then for each row count the rows where `BITAND(mask, myMask) = myMask`. The row (or rows) with the highest count would give you the desired combination.